# EOS in eosio.ram Account

Tags: cleos

Can someone tell me the difference between the four numbers below?

```
eos_node_maurice1@eos-node-maurice1:~$ cleos get currency balance eosio.token eosio.ram EOS
**2289406.8264 EOS**
eos_node_maurice1@eos-node-maurice1:~$ cleos get currency balance eosio.token eosio.ramfee EOS
**1881755.1706 EOS**
eos_node_maurice1@eos-node-maurice1:~$ cleos get table eosio eosio rammarket
{
  "rows": [{
      "supply": "10000000000.0000 RAMCORE",
      "base": {
        "balance": "**32876494967 RAM**",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      },
      "quote": {
        "balance": "**3289416.5960 EOS**",
        "weight": "0.50000000000000000"
      }
    }
  ],
  "more": false
}
```

I am trying to show the real time numbers of staked EOS and EOS in RAM accounts on my website.

Answer (score 1):

> `cleos get currency balance eosio.token eosio.ram EOS`

This reports the amount of EOS held in `eosio.ram` account, which is EOS paid by users for buying RAM (minus fees.) When users sell RAM, they are paid from this account.

> `cleos get currency balance eosio.token eosio.ramfee EOS`

This tells you how much EOS is stored in `eosio.ramfee`, which is the account to which RAM fees are paid--they're supposed to be out of circulation to discourage RAM speculation and potentially offset monetary inflation. Note that accounts pay fees both when selling and when buying RAM.

> `cleos get currency balance eosio.token eosio.ramfee EOS`
>
> - `base.balance`

This is the unused RAM of the system

> - `quote.balance`

This is used to calculate the price for RAM (`quote.balance/base.balance`), and it's the amount of EOS paid for RAM (minus fees) + an initial constant. Thus, this is the number from the first answer + 1,000,000, where 1,000,000 is the initial constant set in [`eosio.system`](https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/75635168e743c3e65bb6345a1eaedd905581e6b0/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.cpp#L32):

```
m.quote.balance.amount = system_token_supply / 1000;
```